# Why is Python function returning a NoneType?

Tags: python, nonetype

I have written two recursive functions in python.

The first one takes parameters, modifies them, and returns a value.

```
def Similarity(string, sstring1, index):
    if condition1:
        return index
    if condition2:
        #do something
    Similarity(string, string1, index)
```

The second one takes parameters and performs operations on a global variable.

```
def getData(i, value):
    global dataList
    if condition:
        return list(suffixList)
    #do something
    getData(i, value)
```

These functions work perfectly and do the exact computations I need but always return a NoneType.

I haven't been able to figure out why.

Comment: Functions without `return smth but None` or without return at all return None.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are not returning *anything*. *Always* use the `return` statement to return a value from a function. Python does *not* use the last statement in a function as a return value.

```
def getData(i, value):
    global dataList
    if condition:
        return list(suffixList)
    #do something
    return getData(i, value)
```

A function that exits without an explicit `return`, returns `None` instead.